# FabricJS object.set() gives not a function error when loading canvas from json

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, fabricjs

After performing actions with fabric js, I convert the content of the canvas to json and save it to localstorage by calling saveAsJson() and when the component mounts because I'm using react, I call the loadContentBack() function which loads back perfectly. But when I start to perform actions on the object I get the error, object.set is not a function, and this error only comes up when I load the canvas content from json.

```js
function saveAsJson() {
        if (canvas) {
            localStorage.setItem("canvasJson", JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON(["id"])));
        }
}
  
 function loadContentBack() {
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("canvasJson") ?? JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON(["id"])));
  
  canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonData, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

loadFromJSON accept `JSON string or object`
[loadFromJSON api](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON)

```js
function loadContentBack() {
  const jsonData = localStorage.getItem("canvasJson") ?? JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON(["id"]));
  
  canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonData, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAu4T.png)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this now but I still get the error and it's so weird because all the objects load correctly the size, color and everything.
And now after moving and changing font-size or color it works initially now but after a while when I select another object the error comes up again.

I'm so confused right now as to what is causing this behavior when loading from json